# Accessing FormData in hapi

Tags: node.js, api, rest, multipartform-data, hapi.js

So Im posting some data from a chrome-extension to my hapi api using XMLHttpRequest:

```
    var xhr =new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://my-url.com/signup', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    let params = {} ;
    params.username = "username";
    params.password = "password";
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params)); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(response){...}
```

Seems to work just fine (from analyzing the network tab in chromes debugger)

Now, on the server-side, coming from Express, I originally thought this data would be available in `req.params`, but some research led me to believe this should work:

```
    module.exports = [{
    method:'POST',
    path: '/signup',
    config:{
        payload:{
            output:'data',
            parse:true,
        },  
    handler:function(request, reply){
        console.log( `signing up user: ${request.payload.username}` );
        .....
    }
    }
}
```

this however prints

> signing up user: undefined

and switching it to print a stringified `request.payload` outputs:

> signing up user: {"{\"username\":\"apa\",\"password\":\"apa\"}":""}

Is there built-in functionality in hapi to parse this, or do I need to "roll my own" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) will format your payload as a `multipart/form-data` payload. But you're setting a Content-type header of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. They're totally different encodings. So you're confusing hapi's payload parser about what encoding of payload it is receiving.

Remove the line:

`xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

It should work then.

Comment: haa! I thought it was strange that hapi wouldnt include a proper parser! cant parse my madness though can it ;P thanks Matt!